# AttributeError: 'FlaskS3' object has no attribute 'url_for'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I'm building a flask application that deploys to AWS Lambda using zappa and I'm trying to use Flask-s3 to handle the static files. I've never used [Flask-S3][1] before and it seemed fairly simple but I'm getting...

`AttributeError: 'FlaskS3' object has no attribute 'url_for'`

They way I understand it you just need to replace your static url's with url_for like so:

```
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'mybucketname'
s3 = FlaskS3(app)

s3.url_for('static/file.jpg')
```

This isn't working so clearly I'm doing something wrong but there is almost nothing online troubleshooting Flask-s3. Anything helps.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
app.config['FLASKS3_BUCKET_NAME'] = 'mybucketname'
s3 = FlaskS3(app)
MAILGUN_API_KEY = 'key'
auth = ('api', MAILGUN_API_KEY)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    context = {
    'image': url_for('static/property_home.jpeg'),
    'heading': 'We sell property - At a discount!',
    'landing_video': url_for('static/intro.mp4')
    }
    form = forms.OptIn()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        validate = requests.get(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/address/private/validate",
            auth=auth,
            params={"address": form.email.data})
        if validate.json()['did_you_mean'] is not None:
            flash('Did you mean {}?'.format(validate.json()['did_you_mean']))
        elif validate.json()['is_valid'] == True and validate.json()['is_role_address'] == False and validate.json()['is_disposable_address'] == False:
            r = requests.post(
            "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/members",
            auth=auth,
            data={'subscribed': True,
                  'address': form.email.data})
            if r.status_code == 200:
                requests.post('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages',
                    auth=auth,
                    data={"from": 'Matt@SpokaneDiscountProperties.com',
                        "to": form.email.data,
                        "subject": "Welcome to Spokane Discount Properties",
                        "html": open('templates/indoc.html'),
                        "o:tag": 'indoctrinated'})
                flash('Thanks, we will notify you when we have more properties')
            else:
                flash('You are already subscribed, we will notify you when more properties are available')
        else:
            flash('Holy guacamole! Best check yo self, this is not a valid email.')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, context=context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc here](https://flask-s3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_s3.FlaskS3.init_app)

> In terms of getting your application to use external Amazon S3 URLs
>   when referring to your application’s static assets, passing your Flask
>   object to the FlaskS3 object is all that needs to be done.

The extension takes care of handling the `url_for` for you. So you might not need to call it directly.

> Internally, every time url_for is called in one of your application’s
>   templates, flask_s3.url_for is instead invoked. If the endpoint
>   provided is deemed to refer to static assets, then the S3 URL for the
>   asset specified in the filename argument is instead returned.
>   Otherwise, flask_s3.url_for passes the call on to flask.url_for.

change this:

```
context = {
    'image': url_for('static/property_home.jpeg'),
    'heading': 'We sell property - At a discount!',
    'landing_video': url_for('static/intro.mp4')
    }
```

to:

```
context = {
    'image': url_for('static', filename= 'property_home.jpeg'),
    'heading': 'We sell property - At a discount!',
    'landing_video': url_for('static', filename='intro.mp4')
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mekicha but I had already tried just using `url_for` by itself. I then get `BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint`

Comment: I need to see your code to be able to help with that. `url_for` expects a function mostly.

Comment: Updated my answer. For static files, you have to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly